# I'm writing into a book about blueprints some of the things Im looking for are not readily avialable

Tags: measurements

I currently just writing notes about the item I am up to.  I'm writing an artisanal war book about fun blueprints someone might like to do as all of the projects presented are brought to the table by me, thought of by me and usefully involve something to do with popular televisions shows brought forward to me.

I'm just going to ask a few questions

Is there a market for toys and book as well maybe as combined packet, maybe to start taking a item forward would be how a 2 foot tall book and a package of metallics infused materials edited to combine into final lesson would work?

Is there anyone I can see to read about as I'm a power forward reading expert that is attempting to have my story straight and similar to a building to be erected the projection was a success?

The thing I'm looking at in my notes is the item at the end is a armored puppet using a repeated pattern to display how the armor is touching the puppet tightly it is translucent and has large stamping in the inside and cylinders coming out to meet outside sheets.

1. What materials are used in the process of homemade crafting in engineering products of a mathematical equation involving items drawing inspiration to build said puppet?

Some of the items involve a spider-man bicycle made of recycled noodle cartoon that is a transformer, the others include super hero outfits, large utility belts that are artisinal karate acceptables, robot knuckles from sonic the hedgehog using paper products and plastic fashion products to produce a sculpture of and into realism a rendered life form.

Comment: Like the books to make paper planes?

Comment: what is a `power forward reading expert`?

Comment: `something to do with popular televisions shows` ... `spider-man bicycle` ... `robot knuckles from sonic the hedgehog` .... you will have to obtain the rights to use these in your book, if you plan to sell the book

Comment: @jstola I thought Tim Duncan, librarian

Comment: Like there are a lot of words here, but I don't understand them.  Try editing and shortening your sentences.  Use less pronouns (it, they, etc.,_ and exactly where you fit.  Because an artisanal war book someone might like to do when the projects are brought to you is hard to parse.

Comment: @TigerGuy thanks for the comments I guess, I think naming a problem of how the items were to fit was going to work.

Comment: @matthewwykoff, but what items and what fitting where?  I don't understand what you are doing.  Is it a book about blueprints?  A kit to build something that comes with a book?  Is the problem how to construct the book?  Do blueprints come separately?

Comment: https://www.walmart.com/ip/The-Book-Blueprint-Expert-Advice-for-Creating-Industry-Standard-Print-Books-Paperback-9780936385457/818219445?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=101183744 is a book about blueprints